# Wrap Actionscript code in loadercomplete() for SWFUpload

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, swfupload

I am trying to use SWFupload client side resize, there is currently an error caused by the blur filter being applied.  I have found a solution online but it only gives a description of the solution not the final swf file.  The answer was....

```
I wrapped the blurFilter code in loaderComplete() in ImageResizer.as with the following     if statement and now everything works like a charm:

if (bmp.width * bmp.height < 0x01000000) {
  // existing blur if statement and code

}
```

I have found the original point in the AS file that I think it is referencing...

```
// Blur it a bit if it is sizing smaller
if (this.newWidth < bmp.width || this.newHeight < bmp.height) {
// Apply the blur filter that helps clean up the resized image result
var blurMultiplier:Number = 1.15; // 1.25;
var blurXValue:Number = Math.max(1, bmp.width / this.newWidth) * blurMultiplier;
var blurYValue:Number = Math.max(1, bmp.height / this.newHeight) * blurMultiplier;

var blurFilter:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(blurXValue, blurYValue,           int(BitmapFilterQuality.LOW));
bmp.applyFilter(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.width, bmp.height), new Point(0, 0),     blurFilter);
}
```

Could somebody a bit more skilled with action script explain how to apply the fix to this code?  I think I am able to recompile to SWF using FlashDevelop